# Recommended way to load Facebook sdk in angular js app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Working angularjs app with facebook with this  module [Angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) at Github, and initialized it like this

```
var mainApp=angular.module('app',['ngMaterial','facebook','services']);
    mainApp.config(function(FacebookProvider) {
         // Set your appId through the setAppId method or
         // use the shortcut in the initialize method directly.
         FacebookProvider.init('532389480270701');
      })



    mainApp.controller('StartUpController', ['$http','Facebook','$scope','Product', function($http,Facebook,$scope,Product){

      $scope.user={};
      $scope.mate={};
      $scope.facebookReady=false;
      $scope.login = function() {
          // From now on you can use the Facebook service just as Facebook api says
          Facebook.login(function(response) {
            // Do something with response.
          });
        };

        $scope.getLoginStatus = function() {
          Facebook.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if(response.status === 'connected') {
              $scope.loggedIn = true;
            } else {
              $scope.loggedIn = false;
            }
          });
        };

        $scope.me = function() {
          Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
            $scope.user = response;
          });
        };
        $scope.getMateInfo=function(){
          Facebook.api(
              '/me/picture',
              'GET',
              {},
              function(response) {
                $scope.mate=response;
              }
            );

        };
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          // This is for convenience, to notify if Facebook is loaded and ready to go.
          return Facebook.isReady();
        }, function(newVal) {
          // You might want to use this to disable/show/hide buttons and else
          $scope.facebookReady = true;
        });
```

and in the html I loaded the module just after angularjs module at the footer.

My problem is the UI shows app and clicking something that uses facebook api ends up with this error

> {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"FU8MECrV+3P"}}

But after a while that means after everything is loaded it shows correct results for the APIs.
How should solve this thing?

1. How can I disable buttons if still loading resources
2. How can load all resources before displaying the UI for the app

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've not used FB api with **js**, but here is my Guess.
I've been able to reproduce you'r error by running $scope.me() before anything else. You probably need to use those functions after authentication / login.

```
// do not show all buttons at first
$scope.showOtherButtons = false;

// call Login
$scope.login()
...
Facebook.login(function(response) {
    // At this point calling $scope.me() should probably be safe.
    $scope.showOtherButtons = true;
});
```

In html use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive to hide all other buttons before you are authenticated, like`

```
<div ng-if="showOtherButtons">... buttons are here </div>
```

Hope this helps.